# Custom HTML tags

Tags: html, css, tags

When I wanted a lot of different looking texts in one div I tried creating a custom tag. 
This was to avoid having to create a new id for each textstyle. 
Is this something you usually do? I also noticed that it worked fine in both Chrome and FX, but the style disappeared in IE. Is there a way to use custom tags in IE?

Comment: Use standard elements and CSS, not custom tags.

Comment: Insufficient details, whats wrong with <span class="pink ...

Comment: id use spans with classes. but if you absolutely want to make custom tags in IE check out [this link](http://ajaxian.com/archives/adding-custom-tags-to-internet-explorer-the-official-way)

Comment: you want to personalise divs, or spans tags (and other). Create custom tags works, because every browser read tags, but it's not valid. Using existing tags, and personalised there with CSS is more clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
document.write ("custom tag1");
document.write ("custom tag2");
....
document.write ("custom tagn");
</script>
```